# method overloading in java web services

Tags: java, web-services, axis

I am using apache axis 1.2 and i tried to implement method overloading in java webservices this is the sample code.

```
//Here i took method1 with two parameters     
public String method1(String s1,String s2)
{
    SampleLogger.error("In method1(1)");
    return "method1(1)";
}    
//Here i took method1 with three parameters     
public String method1(String s1,String s2,String s3) throws RemoteException
{
    SampleLogger.error("In method1(2)");
    return "method1(2)";
}    
//Here i took method1 with four parameters  
public String method1(String s1,String s2,String s3,String s4) throws RemoteException
{
    SampleLogger.error("In method1(3)");
    return "method1(3)";
}
```

When i tried to create these methods as webservice methods, i am getting error
          IWAB0398E Error in generating WSDL from Java:  Attempted to write duplicate

```
schema element : {http://service.codon.com}method1
    AxisFault
    faultCode: {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}Server.generalException
    faultSubcode:
    faultString: Attempted to write duplicate schema element :
```

Answer (score 1):

Still, you could expose your methods with a unique name with the
`@WebMethod(operationName=......)` annotation, though this is not real overloading.